# border property of <option> in google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

when i apply this styles to **option** element:

```
border-color: #8A8A8A #E5E5E5 #E5E5E5 #8A8A8A;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
```

the all browsers display it correctly, but google chrome ignores this styles and rendering double border. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `outline: none` to your CSS rule. This will remove the orange border that Google Chrome puts around the element when focused on.

```
outline:none;
border-color: #8A8A8A #E5E5E5 #E5E5E5 #8A8A8A;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/rLVhp/1/

Comment: yes, but border is still 2px. If i set -webkit-appearance:none, border finally sets to 1px, but right drop down corner is disappeared, and dropdownlist (select) looks like textbox

Comment: the problem is jsfiddle.net displays your example correctly, but google chrome doesn't

Comment: Even when jsfiddle is running in Chrome? Please post your fiddle so we can see

Comment: @Wachburn So this is working for you in jsfiddle but not in your website? Have you tried inspecting the element to see if any styles are overriding?

Comment: it doesn't work neither fiddle nor my web site only in google chrome. Did you try run my fiddle in chrome? border is 2 px?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should disable any pre-style apply to your option element before.

Chrome by default set some style for some element as Options and many other like Textfield and so on.

I already had the same problem, solved by a reset of the default style on the entire element.